# function to check if value exists - php

Tags: php, null

I was wondering if it is possible to have a general system function that checks for a value and if it doesn't exist return another value.

below is what I have come up with however if I use it on a value say $thisvalue but $thisvalue doesn't exist I am getting the error Undefined variable: thisvalue. If thisvalue is empty or null etc below works.

Thanks

```
public function checkingValue($value = NULL, $empty_return = NULL)
{
    if(isset($value))
    {
        return $value;
    }
    else
    {
        return $empty_return;
    }
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        return $value;
    }
    if(!is_null($value))
    {
        return $value;
    }

    return $empty_return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset` and `empty` are not functions, they're actually **language constructs** like `switch` and `list` and `class`.

If you do this:

```
function my_isset($var) {
    return isset($var);
}

isset($undef); // false
my_isset($undef); // Error: Undefined variable: $undef
```

Comment: ok thanks. So is there no way to setup a function like I have to use in cases like this?

Comment: No, you must use `isset` and `empty`. `is_null` is a function so that one doesn't matter. Input checking shouldn't be this hard though, usually just `isset` is enough.